# Error: 42601 syntax error at or near ":" when trying to save data in windoes forms c# program

Tags: c#, postgresql, winforms

I'm making a small program that allows me to insert data into a data table which is connected with PostgreSQL. All functions are working fine on postgresql: select, insert, update and delete.
Here is the code:

```
        private void FrmTeachers_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connstring);
            Select();
            //dgvTabela.Columns["docente_id"].HeaderText = "Teachers ID";
        }  


        private void Select()
        {
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                sql = @"select * from docen_selecionar()";
                cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, conn);
                dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
                conn.Close();
                dgvTabela.DataSource = null;
                dgvTabela.DataSource = dt;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                conn.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }


        private void DgvTabela_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {            
            if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
            {
                txtName.Text = dgvTabela.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["_docente_id"].Value.ToString();
                txtID.Text = dgvTabela.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["_nome_docente"].Value.ToString();
                txtVAT.Text = dgvTabela.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["_nif_number"].Value.ToString();
                txtDepart.Text = dgvTabela.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["_departamento"].Value.ToString();
                txtDegree.Text = dgvTabela.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["_grau_academico"].Value.ToString();
            }
        }

        private void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            rowIndex = -1;
            txtName.Enabled = txtDegree.Enabled = txtDepart.Enabled = txtID.Enabled = txtVAT.Enabled = true;
            txtName.Text = txtDegree.Text = txtDepart.Text = txtID.Text = txtVAT.Text = null;
            txtName.Select();
        }

        private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (rowIndex < 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please choose a Teacher to update");
                return;
            }
            txtName.Enabled = txtDegree.Enabled = txtDepart.Enabled = txtID.Enabled = txtVAT.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (rowIndex < 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please choose a Teacher ID to delete");
                return;
            }

            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                sql = @"select * from docen_apagar(:_docente_id)";
                cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, conn);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_docente_id", int.Parse(dgvTabela.Rows[rowIndex].Cells["docente_id"].Value.ToString()));
                if ((int)cmd.ExecuteScalar() == 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Teacher deleted successfully");
                    rowIndex = -1;
                    Select();
                }
                conn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                conn.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Delete fail. Please try again. Error:" + ex.Message);
            }
        }
        //save - esqueci-me de alterar o name
        private void iconButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int result = 0;

            if (rowIndex < 0) //insert
            {
                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    sql = @"select * from docen_registar(:_docente_id,:_nome_docente,:_departmento,:_grau_academico,:_nif_number)";
                    cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, conn);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_nome_docente", txtName.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_docente_id", txtID.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_departamento", txtDepart.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_grau_academico", txtDegree.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_nif_number", txtVAT.Text);
                    result = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

                    conn.Close();
                    if (result == 1)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Inserted new Teacher successfully");
                        Select();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Inserted fail");
                    }                      

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    conn.Close();
                    MessageBox.Show("Inserted fail, please try again. Error: " + ex.Message);
                }
            }
            else //update
            {

                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    sql = @"select * from docen_update(:_docente_id,:_nome_docente,:_departmento,:_grau_academico,:_nif_number)";
                    cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, conn);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_docente_id", int.Parse(dgvTabela.Rows[rowIndex].Cells["docente_id"].Value.ToString()));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_nome_docente", txtName.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_docente_id", txtID.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_departamento", txtDepart.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_grau_academico", txtDegree.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_nif_number", txtVAT.Text);
                    result = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                    conn.Close();
                    if (result == 1)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Successfully updated");
                        Select();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Updated fail, please try again.");
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    conn.Close();
                    MessageBox.Show("Updated fail, please try again. Error: " + ex.Message);
                }                

            }
            result = 0;
            txtName.Text = txtDegree.Text = txtDepart.Text = txtID.Text = txtVAT.Text = null;
            txtName.Enabled = txtDegree.Enabled = txtDepart.Enabled = txtID.Enabled = txtVAT.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to create 4 buttons: insert, update, delete and save and when I click save it gives the following error:
"Error: 42601 syntax error at or near ":""

I Really don't know what it is.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Possibly the misspell, ":_departmento" in the sql statement and "_departamento" when you addwithvalue.  The parameter is not replaced.

Comment: AddWithValue ought not be used.  See: https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/

Comment: @BjarniRagnarsson I found the misspelling error, but now I have another error: 42883, function docen_registar(text,text,text,text,text) does not exist

Comment: How does this even work if all SQL commands are SELECT * ?

Comment: The function `docen_registar` must be declared/created in the database.

Comment: Chances are, that the function's signature isn't `docen_registar(text,text,text,text,text)` but some other types than `text` as well. Posgres' polymorphism needs the right types of the argument, so thath the right function can be bound. And that is exactly why you shouldn't use `AddWithValue()` as @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp already pointed out. It guesses the type and might be wrong about it. Instead use `Add()` and specify the correct type (in SQL) for the parameter.

Comment: Thank you everyone. I already solved the problem with the text text text using int.parse. But it cannot read the int when I want to delete or update by teacher ID. I think it's because I have this txtName.Text = txtDegree.Text = txtDepart.Text = txtID.Text = txtVAT.Text = null; but the txtID and txtVAT are ints. I tried with the int.parse, but it doesn't work. Do you have an idea how to fix it?